# Use of ていれば + だった

Tags: conditionals

『公園では偶然にも彼と会った。少し焦ったけれど、自然に話していれば別に全然平気だった』

What is the specific use of ていれば in this? He's describing how at the park he meet a friend. He was a bit nervous on what he should talk/how he should act with him.

Is it an "after" conditional? After I did x?

Comment: I think all this is is making it past tense. When you have tense-less verb constructions like -eba, putting the other verb (in this case datta) in past tense makes the whole sentiment past tense. Usually in English we won't use "if" in these instances, rather maybe "as long as." But the idea is the same: "On the condition that I (was) speak(ing) naturally, everything was fine."

Answer (score 0):

"as far as talking naturally, there were no problems"

Comment: How did you get as far?